# sass @include works in some files and not others

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, bourbon, neat

I'm using the sass library 'bourbon neat'. 
It provides a mixin called "outer-container".

I have a sass file structured like this:

```
@import bourbon/bourbon
@import neat/neat

@import componentOne

@import componentTwo
```

I want to use neat from within both the files componentOne and componentTwo.

Within both files I have use the mixin:

```
@include outer-container;
```

If I use the mixin from just within componentOne, I get the result I want.
The mixin gets used.

If I use the mixin from within componentTwo, my gulp-sass throws the Error:

> Error: no mixin named outer-container
>
> ```
>    Backtrace:
>       componentTwo.scss
>     on line 3 of componentTwo.scss
> ```
>
> @include outer-container;

I could cheat by importing the entire library into the second file.
But if I read the sass docs right, the **mixin** should be available to both `componentOne.scss` and `componentTwo.scss`, because they are both `@imported` into a file that already imports the library.

What's going on here?
How do I use the library in all my sass files without importing it into each file?

Comment: Are you sure both component are in same directory and you included correctly this: `@include outer-container;` in your both component? Not able to see what you are missing.

Comment: Hi @AvneshShakya. Yes, both components are in the same directory. And the line '@include outer-container' is included within css blocks in both files. And yet 'outer-container' is only available to componentOne. Afaict, I'm doing everything by the docs. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't see it.

Comment: I mean, just to be clear: if I cut blocks of code from componentOne.scss (specifically blocks that use code from neat) and paste them into componentTwo.scss, then I get the error.